# Binding with .on Event of Jquery

Tags: jquery

I used a autocomplete plugin for my site. It was working well for me. But now As I used Ajax same time So while adding new HTML using AJax my script failed.
I posted on stackoverflow and got answer as to use `.on` of Jquery 1.7.2 So I tried to binded my code to `.on`

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $(document).on("click.autocomplete","#artist_id",function(e){
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source : '<?php echo HTTP_PATH . '/artists/getArtistList'; ?>',
                multiple: true,
                mustMatch: true,
                matchContains: true,
                scroll: true,
                minChars: 0,
                autoFill: true,
                dataType: "json",
                parse: function(data) {
                    return $.map(data, function(item) {
                        return { data: item, value: item.label, result: item.label};
                    });
                },
                formatItem: function(item) {
                    return item.label;
                },
                formatResult: function(item) {
                    return item.id;
                },
                formatMatch: function(item) {
                    return item.label;
                }
            });
        });
    });
 });
```

The code which was working well...

```
    $("#artist_id").focus().autocomplete( '<?php //echo HTTP_PATH . '/artists/getArtistList'; ?>', {
        multiple: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        matchContains: true,
        scroll: true,
        minChars: 0,
        autoFill: true,
        dataType: "json",
        parse: function(data) {
            return $.map(data, function(item) {
                return { data: item, value: item.label, result: item.label};
            });
        },
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return item.label;
        },
        formatResult: function(item) {
            return item.id;
        },
        formatMatch: function(item) {
            return item.label;
        }
    });
```

Issue is neither it send response nor it give me error with script. I tried to check it using Firebug.

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log("something here") in your script to see if you're getting there? I suspect it is this not binding properly.
$(document).on("click.autocomplete","#artist_id",function(e){
try 
$(document).on("click","#artist_id",function(e){

Comment: Can u guide to put logconsole. New with it.

Comment: Right above this line  $(this).autocomplete({ put console.log("I made it"); Then in fire bug if you look at the console if you see I made it, you are getting into that function.

Comment: I am get 'I made it' in my console i.e firebug.

Comment: You have $(function(){ }); inside a $(document).ready, they do the same thing

Comment: Also $(document).on("click.autocomplete","#artist_id",function(e){
this doesn't need to be in a $(document).ready.

Comment: I already tried and put it out.. as per hint by answeres... NO bug is generating and no solution yet,,, Completely confused

Comment: The lack of an error and no functionality generally means it is a logic problem. Follow your program line by line the way the browser reads it. Debug it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
$(document).on("click.autocomplete","#artist_id",function(e){
```

You previously were 'binding' on focus, now you're binding on 'click.autocomplete'.  Change it to this:

```
$(document).on("focus","#artist_id",function(e){
```

Per the [jQuery docs on .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/%20jQuery%20docs%20on%20.on%28%29), the second parameter is the event you want to bind to, not a selector.

Comment: It isn't showing an error because it sounds like it isn't binding properly.

Comment: @rickm per the jQuery docs on `.on()`  (which you linked to) the second parameter is an optional selector, the first parameter is always the event.

Comment: @KevinB since he's using `$(document)` he needs the selector.  Depending on whether that's a dynamic element or not, you could potentially leave out that parameter and just do `$('#artist_id');`

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you are incorrect in the statement `Per the jQuery docs on .on(), the second parameter is the event you want to bind to, not a selector.`, it is backwards... the first parameter is the event and the second parameter is the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

This is redundant

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){...
```

only use one or the other.

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

Secondly, `click.autocomplete` binds to any click events that have the `autocomplete` namespace. What i think you meant to do is to bind the event to any text input that has the class `autocomplete`.

```
$(document).on("click",".autocomplete",function(e){
    // prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();
    // initialize autocomplete
    $(this).autocomplete({
        ...
    })
    // remove class to prevent reinitializing autocomplete:
    .removeClass('autocomplete')
    // trigger the focus event to start the autocomplete
    .focus();
});
```

`$(document).ready` isn't needed here since the `document` is already ready.